# How to recover the standby database after opening

Tags: oracle, dataguard, standby

If I have standby which is db role is PHYSICAL STANDBY and it is MOUNTED. So, when I open it read/write the standby will be destroyed. (I have DataGuard)

So, basically do I need to mount it again and start the recover process to fix it or does this envolve more steps?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do that with recovery only. The standby database that was opened in read/write mode must be flashed backed to a point before it was opened.

This concept is called "snapshot standby".

[Managing a Snapshot Standby Database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sbydb/managing-oracle-data-guard-physical-standby-databases.html#GUID-CE30E2D6-5B53-4389-8B02-FC0F341C8C1A)

> A snapshot standby database is a fully updatable standby database. It
> receives and archives redo data from a primary database, but does not
> apply it.
>
> Redo data received from the primary database is applied when a
> snapshot standby database is converted back into a physical standby
> database, after discarding all local updates to the snapshot standby
> database.
>
> ...
>
> Flashback Database is used to convert a snapshot standby database
> back into a physical standby database. Any operation that cannot be
> reversed using Flashback Database technology prevents a snapshot
> standby from being converted back to a physical standby.

More details can be found in the documentation referenced above.

With broker:

[Converting a Physical Standby to a Snapshot Standby](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dgbkr/examples-using-data-guard-broker-DGMGRL-utility.html#GUID-13FDC86F-A736-44F0-A2DD-33B7FF3067A7)

Comment: so basically only few commands, will restore my database to functional standby db again?

Comment: @paganini Anything can be done with only a few commands that are wrappers for additional steps, but yes, that is the point of this.

Comment: thanks for the info, I have 1 more additional questions, lets suppouse I have windows server which is my standby. Can I use configure the database to startup immediatly or do I need a small script which would start after every windows restart?